# Prevent automatic JScrollPane viewport change on content resize

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane with a custom JPanel as the content. The scrollpane has a mouse wheel handler, so when the user scrolls, the content is 'zoomed', and the JPanel becomes larger in height.

I need to ensure that the user's viewport maintains position on the current row of pixels on the JPanel that are currently under the mouse. However, when I manually try and set the viewport in the wheel handler, I can't ensure consistent focus, as sometimes the JScrollPane overrides my changes with the default behaviour for when JScrollPane's content becomes larger.

I've made a simple example showing the structure of my program as below, however the example only tries to ensure the viewport focus remains on the bottom of the JPanel when scrolling in as the panel doubles in size. The scroll wheel causes the JPanel to double/halve in height.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Test extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t= new Test();
        t.show();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        BorderLayout blm = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(blm);

        getContentPane().add(new MyScroller(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyScroller extends JScrollPane implements MouseWheelListener
    {
        static InnerPanel controlGrid = new InnerPanel();
        int panelHeight = 200;

        public MyScroller() 
        {
            super(controlGrid, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            this.setBackground(Color.blue);
            this.addMouseWheelListener(this);

            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        @Override
        public void revalidate()
        {
            super.revalidate();

            if (controlGrid != null)
            {
                controlGrid.revalidate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            draw(g);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g)
        {
        }


        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            String message;
            int direction = 1;
            int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
            if (notches < 0) {
                panelHeight += panelHeight;
            } else {
                panelHeight -= (panelHeight > panelHeight ? panelHeight : 0);
            }

            controlGrid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, panelHeight));
            controlGrid.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, panelHeight));

            repaint();

            this.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(0, panelHeight));
        }

        static class InnerPanel extends JPanel
        {
            public InnerPanel(){

                this.setBackground(Color.red);
                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 600));
                this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 600));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to change size from paintComponent(). Paint must just paint.

Comment: Okay thanks, so I'm now setting the minimum size of the JPanel to the new height inside the wheel listener. However it seems that this sizing isn't actually being applied immediately - the furthest I can scroll down is only as far as the previous height and not the new height that has been set inside the handler.

How can I either force the resizing to be applied immediately or somehow trigger my viewport change immediately after the resize event occurs?